# constructor Circle in class Circle cannot be applied to given types

Tags: javafx

I was trying out javafx Circle library demo, I copied the code from an example, but it does not seem to compile. My code  is

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Circle extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Circle Demo");
        Circle circle = new Circle(150.0f, 150.0f, 80.f);
        Group group = new Group(circle);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 500, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The error I get is

> Circle.java:11: error: constructor Circle in class Circle cannot be applied to given types;
>           Circle circle = new Circle(150.0f, 150.0f, 80.f);

Comment: The class name seems to be ambiguous.

Comment: Because your class is called `Circle` and you don't define a constructor so Java will generate the default no-args constructor. So it cannot find a constructor with 4 parameters. Easy fix would be to rename your `Circle` class or make the call with the fully qualified name: `javafx.scene.shape.Circle`

Comment: Don't use an existing class name for your own class, especially  when you import a class with the same name in the file ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ambiguity in your class name. It shares the same name with `Circle` class in `javafx.scene.shape` package.

So, `new Circle(150.0f, 150.0f, 80.f);` here refers to the current class, instead of `javafx.scene.shape.Circle`.

Two ways to Fix this:

1. Fully qualified class names can be used. Changing the code to `new javafx.scene.shape.Circle(150.0f, 150.0f, 80.f);` will refer the required package.
2. Changing the name of your class to a different name, which does not share the library's class name. As in, changing the name of the class from `Circle` to `CircleDemo` would fix this problem.

The second approach is recommended, as it can be quite confusing to have class names similar to library classes.